# Run time error, Jolly jumpers

Tags: c, runtime-error

Im solving the Jolly Jumpers problem using an online compiler: https://ideone.com/. Its shows me the correct answer but tells me that there is a run time error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int n,a[3000];

    do
    {
        int aux=0,j=1, i;

        scanf("%i",&n);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%ui",&a[i]);
        }


        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<a[i+1])
            {
                if((a[i+1]-a[i])==(n-j)){
                    aux++;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }

            }else{
                if((a[i]-a[i+1])==(n-j))
                    aux++;

                else
                    break;
            }

            j++;
        }
        if(aux==(n-1))
            printf("Jolly");

        else
            printf("Not jolly");
    }
    while(!feof(stdin));
    return 0;
}
```

The rune time error is in the `while(!feof(stdin)`, makes an infinity loop, is there another way to read from the keyboard and at the same time evaluate? . Thanks for the help.

Comment: And this runtime error is...?

Comment: You forgot to `return 0;` at the end of `main`.

Comment: the while(!feof(stdin), makes an infinity loop

Answer (score 0):

The feof function returns a nonzero value if a read operation has attempted to read past the end of the file; it returns 0 otherwise.

scanf has not "read past the end of the file". So feof will always return 0 which causes the infinite loop.

I think what you want to do is to hang on the keyboard until the user presses a key then exit, right?

Try just reading again with scanf. You may want to first print a message saying "Press Enter to exit the program".

Eddy

Comment: Oh, and just scanf, don't use a while.

Comment: how do you use scanf like that?

Comment: scanf("%c", &my_char); // hang on the keyboard until Enter is pressed